# Convert DataFrameGroupBy object to Dict without Index column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to do a *groupby* on my *dataframe* (like below):

```
    VendorID  ProductID  Qty     Expiring   Date
    123456    P789456     1195    True       xyz
    123456    P123456     1015    True       xyz
    987564    P168816     251     False      xyz
    123456    P900456     1222    True       xyz
```

I want a dictionary like below i.e. column names as Keys & the row values as Value of the Key (**NOTE**: Without the **INDEX** column of *dataframe*):

```
[
   {
      'vendorid': 123456,
      'products': [
                      {'productid': 'P789456', 'qty': 1195},
                      {'productid': 'P123456', 'qty': 1015},
                      {'productid': 'P900456', 'qty': 1222}
                   ],
      'expiring': True
      'date': 'xyz'
   },
   {
      'vendorid': 987564,
      'products': [
                      {'productid': 'P168816', 'qty': 251},
                   ],
      'expiring': False
      'date': 'xyz'
   },
   ...
   ...
]
```

I was trying

```
df = df.groupby('vendorid')[['productid', 'qty', 'expiring', 'date']]

df = df.apply(lambda x: x.set_index('productid').to_dict(orient='index')).to_dict()
```

on `df` but getting errors.

Appreciate any clue/direction with a little bit of explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
(df.groupby(['VendorID', 'Date', 'Expiring'])
   .apply(lambda g: dict(zip(g['ProductID'], g['Qty'])))
   .reset_index(name='productid')
   .to_dict('records')
)
```

Output:

```
[{'VendorID': 123456,
  'Date': 'xyz',
  'Expiring': True,
  'productid': {'P789456': 1195, 'P123456': 1015, 'P900456': 1222}},
 {'VendorID': 987564,
  'Date': 'xyz',
  'Expiring': False,
  'productid': {'P168816': 251}}]
```

Or for a more customizable output, with a dictionary comprehension:

```
[{'vendorid': k, 'productid': dict(zip(g['ProductID'], g['Qty'])),
  'expiring': g['Expiring'].all(), 'Date': g['Date'].max()}
 for k, g in df.groupby('VendorID')]
```

##### alternative format

```
out = [
 {'vendorid': k,
  'products': [{'productid': a, 'qty': b}
               for a,b in zip(g['Qty'], g['ProductID'])],
  'expiring': g['Expiring'].all(),
  'Date': g['Date'].max()}
 for k, g in df.groupby('VendorID')
]
```

Output:

```
[{'vendorid': 123456,
  'products': [{'productid': 1195, 'qty': 'P789456'},
               {'productid': 1015, 'qty': 'P123456'},
               {'productid': 1222, 'qty': 'P900456'}],
  'expiring': True,
  'Date': 'xyz'},
 {'vendorid': 987564,
  'products': [{'productid': 251, 'qty': 'P168816'}],
  'expiring': False,
  'Date': 'xyz'}]
```

Comment: Thanks @morzay ! The first option is good, using zip really good trick.

Comment: A little change in requirement @mozway, updated the question

Comment: @iPaul I updated the answer, but please don't change the logic of the question after an answer was given next time.